# glibc-2 is required for this package

Tags: glibc, deadbeef

I'm pretty new to the Linux world and I'm trying to compile a plugin for DeaDBeeF that's located in [this git repo](https://github.com/Serranya/deadbeef-mpris2-plugin). The instructions say:

```
===== How to install =====
- git clone https://github.com/Serranya/deadbeef-mpris2-plugin.git
- cd deadbeef-mpris2-plugin
- autoreconf --install
- ./configure
- make install
```

So I did that. I got to the `./configure` part, and everything works fine until it hits this error:

```
"checking for GLIB_DEPS... no
configure: error: glibc-2 is required for this package"
```

I have libc6 installed and it's up to date, so I don't know what its problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libdb1-compat`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the -dev version of glib. Try installing

```
libglib2.0-dev
```

and maybe

```
build-essential
```

See also: https://github.com/Serranya/deadbeef-mpris2-plugin/issues/13 if you installed DeaDBeeF from the .deb from the DeaDBeeF website