# Media players & KDE Connect multimedia control

Tags: 18.04, kde, multimedia, kde-connect

What Linux players can be controlled through KDE Connect from an Android phone?

I have tested some - **VLC, SMPlayer, Cantata** - that work, I know that **Amarok** works too. Other media players that I use, like mpv, Qmmp and Deadbeef, are not accessed though.

Is there an exhaustive list of the supported players?

Is it possible to make accessible some that are not accessed by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the KDE Connect /1, 2, 3/ mailing list the KDE Connect supports mediaplayer if they implement the MPRIS /4, 5/ interface.

By the KDE Connect mailing list /6/ there should be a MPRIS2 interface plugin for the DeaDBeeF /7/.

**Links**

1. https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect
2. https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/kdeconnect
3. https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kdeconnect/2016-September/001646.html
4. https://community.kde.org/MPRIS
5. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/
6. https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/kdeconnect/2016-September/001648.html
7. https://github.com/Serranya/deadbeef-mpris2-plugin

Therefore, you have to see if the MPRIS interface can be enabled or added to the player as an extension or plugin.

---

**Qmmp** has the mpris plugin, but it is disabled by default and needs to be enabled under Settings-Plugins-General section:

[image]

---

**MPV** video player can also get KDE Connect-ed (as described [here](https://github.com/hoyon/mpv-mpris)) like so: download the mpris plugin from [here](https://github.com/hoyon/mpv-mpris/releases) (64bit-only), copy the `mpris.so` file into the directory `~/.config/mpv/scripts`, restart session.

---

**Clementine** is by default accessible through KDE-Connect; it is qt-based and widely popular.

---

**[QMPlay2](https://github.com/zaps166/QMPlay2)** is another multimedia player that is supported. The Mpris2 plugin is enabled by default in "Settings->Modules->Extensions" (I had to disable and re-enable it to make it work though).

Comment: installing `deadbeef-mpris2-plugin` as indicated at the given link, and also `libglib2.0-dev` to make that installation work, as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/728659/47206),  deadbeef 0.7.2 is not yet seen my KDEConnect though.

Comment: on the other hand, Qmmp has the mpris plugin, it only needs it enabled

Answer (score 0):

According this ([list](https://community.kde.org/MPRIS)) also vlc should be compatible to the MPRIS interface. But I didn't find any way to use my vlc player on windows with kde-connect. Am I missing something, a plugin or so? There seems to be no information on that topic available...